# Power BI - Competitor Average Price Measure

Tags: excel, powerbi-desktop

Attached is the data I have the question for.

I want to create a **Measure** in Power BI that gives me the average price of a competitor's farm product. (If looking at Beth's product, I want to see the average of Amy's product.)

If a filter is applied (example: Product type = Fruit) then I want to see the average price of Amy's fruits). The goal of this is to find the % difference each product is from its filtered competition.

[Spreadsheet data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9baB8.png)

My unsuccessful attempt:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your synax is correct in each variable? If you just pull competitor stuff is it returning the values you would expect in `Measure 2`?

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73574936/edit). Thanks in advance.